# написание sql запроса

Tags: sql, psql

Есть такая вот таблица.
Помогите написать sql запрос, чтобы вывести имена тех пользователей у которых зарплата больше чем у начальника.
В этой таблице например начальник Васька Коля, и Васек получает больше чем его начальник и надо его вывести.[image: таблица]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: Программирование в Пайнте - м-м-м!

Comment: Если программист художник, почему бы и нет. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.name
  FROM employees AS e,
       employees AS c
 WHERE e.id_chief = c.id
   AND e.salary > c.salary
```

Answer (score -1):

Запрос для БД MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary > 20000;
```